# align 3 images in same row with equal spaces?

Tags: html, css

i want to align 3 images in same row in a div, the 1st image should be aligned to complete left of page, the third image should be aligned to complete right of the page and the 2nd image should be aligned in exact center of 1st and 3 rd images

tried the below code but its diaplaying the way i want, how to align the 3 images with the 2nd image placed exactly in the center of the other 2 images?

```
 <div>
 <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image1.bmp")" alt="" align="left" />
 <div id="content" align="center"> 
 <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image2.bmp")" alt="" align="center" />
 </div>
 <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image3.bmp")" alt="" align="right"/>
 </div>


 <style type="text/css">
 #content {


 width:50%;
 margin-left: auto ;
 margin-right:auto ;


 }
```

Answer (score 5):

### The modern approach: flexbox

Simply add the following CSS to the container element (here, the `div`):

```
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""  /> 
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""  />
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
</div>
```

### The old way (for ancient browsers - prior to flexbox)

Use `text-align: justify;` on the container element.

Then stretch the content to take up 100% width

### MARKUP

```
<div>
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""  /> 
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""  />
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    text-align: justify;
}

div img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
div {
    text-align: justify;
}

div img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""  /> 
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""  />
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Any way to get rid of the vertical space caused by the div:after content: '' part ?

Answer (score 2):

- Option 1:

  - Instead of putting the images inside div put each one of them inside a span.
  - Float 1st and 2nd image to left.
  - Give some left padding to the 2nd image.
  - Float the right image to right.

Always remember to add `overflow:hidden` to the parent  (if you have one) of all the images because using floats with images have some side effects.

- Option 2 (Preferred):

  - Put all the images inside a table with border="0".
  - Make the width of the table 100%.

This will be the best way to make sure the 2nd image is alligned to the center always without worrying for the exact width of the table.

Something like below:

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>    
  <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image1.bmp")" alt="" align="left" /></td>
  <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image2.bmp")" alt="" align="center" /></td>
  <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image3.bmp")" alt="" align="right"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is not making the center image exactly between the other 2 images,this is making the 2nd image more close towards the left image

Comment: This seems to break mobile layouts.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <span>
        <img ... >
    </span>
    <span>
        <img ... >
    </span>
    <span>
        <img ... >
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{ width:50%; margin:0 auto; text-align:center}
.container span{ width:30%; margin:0 1%;  }
```

I haven't tested this, but hope this will work.

You can add 'display:inline-block' to .container span to make the span to have fixed 30% width

Comment: this is making the images to overlap on one another

Answer (score 1):

This should be your answer

```
<div align="center">
 <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image3.bmp")" alt="" align="right" style="float:right"/>
 <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image1.bmp")" alt="" align="left" style="float:left" />
 <div id="content" align="center"> 
     <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image2.bmp")" alt="" align="center" />
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: this is working fine for 1024 X 768 screen resolution, when im changing the resolution to 1280 X 800, the middle image is not coming exact in between the 2 images, its more towards teh left image

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the first DIV is `#content` :

```
<div id="content">
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image1.bmp")" alt="" />
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image2.bmp")" alt="" />
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/image3.bmp")" alt="" />
</div>
```

And CSS :

```
#content{
         width: 700px;
         display: block;
         height: auto;
     }
     #content > img{
        float: left; width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 5px 8px;
     }
```